# Jira PDF View Plugin string formatting

Tags: pdf, jira

I realize this is a pretty specific question, but the vendor forum is inactive.  My question is regarding a plugin for JIRA called *PDF View Plugin*.  It allows for some Java to be done, but I'm having some problems formatting a string properly.  I have a 9-digit numerical string that I want to output in my PDF template, but the string is getting formatted in scientific notation (which I don't want).  Any ideas on how to do this type of string formatting in the PDF template?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debated just deleting this question, but in case someone else finds this useful the solution is to use this tool `$!number.format('###,###.00', $variable)`.  In case others are evaluating the plugin, the developers were very prompt in responding.

**Edit:** If you want to just display a whole number, this worked for me: `$!number.format('#', $variable)`